# How to apply multiple custom functions on multiple columns in grouped DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` which is grouped by `p_id`.
The goal is to get a `DataFrame` with data shown under 'Output I'm looking for'.
I've tried a few things, but I am struggling applying two custom aggregated functions:

- `apply(list)` for `x_id`
- `'||'.join` for `x_name`.

How can I solve this problem?

**Input**

```
| p_id | x_id | x_name |
|------|------|--------|
| 1    | 4    | Text   |
| 2    | 4    | Text   |
| 2    | 5    | Text2  |
| 2    | 6    | Text3  |
| 3    | 4    | Text   |
| 3    | 7    | Text4  |
```

**Output I'm looking for**

```
| p_id | x_ids   | x_names            |
|------|---------|--------------------|
| 1    | [4]     | Text               |
| 2    | [4,5,6] | Text||Text2||Text3 |
| 3    | [4,7]   | Text||Text4        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do:

```
df.groupby('pid').agg({'x_id':list, 'x_name':'||'.join})
```

Or a little more advanced with named agg:

```
df.groupby('pid').agg(x_ids=('x_id',list),
                      x_names=('x_name', '||'.join))
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know you could use custom functions with `agg`! :)